# Word VBA checkboxes with link to image that needs to be built up

Tags: image, vba, checkbox, ms-word, code-generation

I am having problems with a table containing checkboxes in Word. 
I am working with a table containing 10 checkboxes. Next to this table, there is an image.
When the user checks one of the checkboxes, something has to be added to the image, i.e. the image is further completed.
However, the order of checking the checkboxes is not fixed or defined, so there are lots of different combinations. 
Is there a way to add the additional parts to the original image, linked to the checkboxes? Or is this way too advanced for Word?

Answer (score 1):

Word doesn't have this type of built-in functionality with images. There are too many state combinations for the checkboxes to make an image for each state in advance. One possibility could be to find a dll or ocx and draw the image programatically (advanced). Another would be to edit your image in photoshop and cut it up into 10 separate files using a transparent background. You could then add and remove layers to wherever you are displaying your image and control the z-ordering with vb.